# Help needed identifying a science fiction piece that was published in the National Lampoon?

Tags: story-identification, horror

A story published (I'm pretty sure) in *[National Lampoon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Lampoon_(magazine))* magazine when I was a teenager, so 50 years ago, give or take.

The main thing I remember about it: A man has sex with a woman whose vagina (somehow) has a “time portal” in it. So through a long chain of events, he comes to cut off his own penis.

I know. This sounds crazy, but I swear it was real.

Comment: I do not recall this in the book, but it might not be entirely out of character for *National Lampoon's Doon* in some kind of send up of Herbert's Bene Gesserit from the novel which is being parodied? Welcome to SFF.SE, Tony.

Comment: Of all the bizarre, nasty, and strangely-appealing-to-a-15-year-old-boy (when I had my subscription) NL stories, how did I miss this one?

Comment: I did some pdfgrep searchs on a NatLamp archive for "time portal" and "time machine" and didn't turn up the story. Given the nature of the magazine, similar searches for "vagina" or "penis" are going to turn up too many results to be useful. Can you remember any other details that might help in a text search?

Comment: What I can remember is the protagonist was in bed when suddenly a disembodied, erect penis appeared in mid-air and I believe started "poking" him. He was justifiably freaked out and grabbed hold of it. Somehow he had a knife nearby so he ended up cutting it off the presumably invisible body. Then some period of time later, a few months or something. He was having sex with a woman when he suddenly had the sensation of his penis being grabbed from INSIDE HER and then it was cut off. So obviously, he cut his own penis off in the past. I know this is a bizarre request, but it's driving me crazy.

Answer (score 12):

This is "Another Cock Tale" by Chris Miller in the May 1975 issue.
It begins with a theoretical physicist awakening to having the sensation of something squirting on his face. Then he notices the disembodied... member.

Comment: Sounds like something that Harlan Ellison would have included in 'The Last Dangerous Visions' if it had ever been published.

Comment: Confirmed correct by checking the archive! Nice job. The 'time machine' is an experimental IUD birth control device.

Comment: That's it! Question answered! Thanks so much!

Comment: I know this question was just asked for nostalgia purposes, and though it is admittedly interesting, as is this answer, that interest is limited, and so no one is going to bother to click [here](https://archive.org/download/PulpMags/National%20Lampoon/), find the link to the 1975-05 "Medicine" issue, click _that_, and scroll down to the 49th page of the PDF, so I don't know why I bothered to post that link.